# How to call a connection variable in class in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have my **connection.php** file.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PWD, DB_DB);
```

I included this file to my **index.php** file.I have some other class files included to **index.php** file.

```
<?php
include('system/includes/config.php');
require_once('system/classes/profile.php');
```

my **profile.php** class is below

```
<?php
class Profile{
function getProfileData(){
    $sql    =   "SELECT * From profile";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    return $result; 
}
}
```

My question is how can in use the connection variable to pass in `mysqli_query`

Comment: You can pass it as a parameter. Create a constructor for your class passing the connection to it, then apply to a private variable inside the class.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes can you please post an answer

Answer (score 1):

A *canonical* way would be to make it a class variable

```
<?php
class Profile{
    public function __construct($mysqli)
    {
        $this->db = $mysqli;
    }
    function getProfileData(){
        $sql    =   "SELECT * From profile";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $result; 
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks,what is $mysqli and how to define it?is it my connection in connection.php

Comment: this is your $conn variable

Comment: what is the difference if i pass my connection value directly and use it in to mysqli_query() and with your answer.sorry asking for learning purpose

Comment: The difference is that my answer is OOP while passing values around is a procedural spaghetti. Besides, in my answer it takes less code to write.

Comment: I got a Warning: Missing argument 1 for Profile::__construct(), called in..
Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in ...
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in

Answer (score 0):

You can set one parameter to your function to make it independent of other code. Just

```
function getProfileData($conn){
```

Comment: bet me to it ;) ahaha

Comment: i just turn my comment into the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Parse the `$conn` variable as a parameter in the function:

```
function getProfileData($conn){
    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM profile";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    return $result; 
}
```

Comment: Have you ever seen a real life application that is *indeed* using such an approach of sending a database connection variable into every method as a parameter?

Comment: @YourCommonSense huh?

Answer (score -1):

```
function init () {
  require_once ('Your connection file');
  // db staying private here
  $db = new MysqliDb ('DB_SERVER', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASS', 'DB_NAME');
}
public function f_name(){
  $db = MysqliDb::getInstance();
}
```

Use your connection as above